# Initialize static variable with static variable got different result in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, static

I am using c++11 to writing a program, and I got `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0` error. So I try to write a small test program to extract the problem part and find what's wrong. Here is my test program:

In common.h file:

```
#include <string>

class CommonUtil
{
  public:
    static const std::string STR_A;
    static const std::string STR_B;
    static const std::string STR_C;

    static const int INT_A;
    static const int INT_B;
    static const int INT_C;
};
```

In common.cc file:

```
#include "common.h"

const std::string CommonUtil::STR_A = "A";
const std::string CommonUtil::STR_B = "B";
const std::string CommonUtil::STR_C = "C";

const int CommonUtil::INT_A = 2;
const int CommonUtil::INT_B = 4;
const int CommonUtil::INT_C = 6;
```

In main.cc file:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

#include "common.h"

static const std::map<int, std::string> map_test =
{
  {1, CommonUtil::STR_A},
  {2, CommonUtil::STR_B},
  {3, CommonUtil::STR_C}
};

static const std::map<int, int> int_map_test =
{
  {1, CommonUtil::INT_A},
  {2, CommonUtil::INT_B},
  {3, CommonUtil::INT_C}
};

class Test
{
  public:
    bool IsItemInMap(int item);
    bool IsItemInIntMap(int item);
};

bool Test::IsItemInMap(int item)
{
  std::cout << "map_test:" << std::endl;
  for (auto &p : map_test)
  {
    std::cout << p.first << ": " << p.second << std::endl;
  }
  if (map_test.find(item) != map_test.end())
  {
    std::cout << "value: " << map_test.at(item) << std::endl;
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

bool Test::IsItemInIntMap(int item)
{
  std::cout << "int_map_test:" << std::endl;
  for (auto &p : int_map_test)
  {
    std::cout << p.first << ": " << p.second << std::endl;
  }

  if (int_map_test.find(item) != int_map_test.end())
  {
    std::cout << "value: " << int_map_test.at(item) << std::endl;
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

int main()
{
  Test test;
  if (test.IsItemInMap(2))
  {
    std::cout << "found!" << std::endl;
  }
  else
  {
    std::cout << "not found!" << std::endl;
  }

  if (test.IsItemInIntMap(2))
  {
    std::cout << "found!" << std::endl;
  }
  else
  {
    std::cout << "not found!" << std::endl;
  }
}
```

My compile command: `g++ -std=c++11 main.cc common.cc`

The program do not get `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0` error but the result confuse me more:

```
map_test:
1: 
2: 
3: 
value: 
found!
int_map_test:
1: 2
2: 4
3: 6
value: 4
found!
```

**I got the expected static map which is initialized with the static int variables, but it do not work with static string variables.**

Why the difference?

By the way, the original program got `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0` error at the `map_test` defination line.

Comment: Order of initialization of global variables defined in different translation units is unspecified. It is possible that the initializer for `map_test` runs before that for `STR_A` et al, whereupon your program exhibits undefined behavior by way of using an object before its lifetime has started.

Comment: Can't find a dupe right now but look up Static initialization order fiasco